# Navbar remove spacing - CSS or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, navbar

So I have this navbar I'm making; I have a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pZy8V) to demonstrate. If you hover over an element, the sublist appears, but if you look carefully, its left edge is just 1 pixel in front of the navbar element that summoned it.

Is there any CSS rule I can add to get rid of this i.e. move the sublist back a pixel? I know it is possible to achieve this with JS (get every navbar element, calculate its distance from the left, take its sublist and give it a left value of one less than that of the element), but for now I'd like to avoid it for now.

I'd prefer a CSS solution if possible, but of course it it isn't, please tell me and, if you can, provide a JS alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jus add `margin-left: -1px;` to your `#nav li:hover ul` to push it 1 pixel to the left.

[see it working here.](http://jsfiddle.net/pZy8V/1/)

Comment: Ah right, margins were the first thing I tried, but I think they didn't work because I appended the rule to the wrong elements D: So thanks for the help, now I know where to add the rule :D

Answer (score 1):

Negative margins to the rescue
http://jsfiddle.net/pZy8V/4/

```
#nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 0 0 -1px; /* margin: 0; */
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
#nav li:hover li {
    float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove all of your borders the problem goes away. So the answer may lie in redesigning your HTML/CSS border usage

See this revided [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLQeV/1/)

If you just want a quick and dirty fix you can add the following to your original CSS

```
#nav li {
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    left:-1px;
}
```

Comment: if the borders are removed, the complete design changes. this obviously isn't a good solution as it only hides the problem instead of solving it.

Comment: I updated the answer with a specific fix for you. Putting too many "-1px" fixes in ayour CSS can _sometimes_ lead to inconsistencies between browsers. If you're using a `strict` DocType you should be ok.